# How to code controller for mvc3 file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@model Framely2011.Models.PictureUpload

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<h2>Upload</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" />

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MetaTagsObj.Meta1)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MetaTagsObj.Meta2)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MetaTagsObj.Meta3)<br />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

This is what I have so far, here is what my model looks like:

```
public class PictureUpload
    {
        public HttpPostedFile fileName { get; set; }
        public MetaTags MetaTagsObj { get; set; }
    }
```

I am not sure how to write my controller for the picture upload or how to upload the file at the controller when I do a `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I have done it in the past (asp.net mvc 2)... There may very well be a much easier way to do it with .net 4 and asp.net mvc 3

```
foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
            {
                if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile()) continue;

                string mimeType = Request.Files[upload].ContentType;
                Stream fileStream = Request.Files[upload].InputStream;
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
                int fileLength = Request.Files[upload].ContentLength;
                byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
                fileStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);
                //do something with the byte array (filedata)
            }
```

HasFile() is an extension method defined like:

```
public static class HttpPostedFileBaseExtensions
{
    public static bool HasFile(this HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        return (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0);
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: There is never a reason to write `x ? true : false`.

Comment: LOL, you're right... I got the code off a blog and obviously didn't look at it very closely :#  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can just take your model as a parameter in the `[HttpPost]` action method and read the `fileName` property.